# Converting a first order system into a higher order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is from a homework assignment but i feel like i really dont have enough information, the course just started and we haven't learned anything yet...

Find the sufficient and necessary condition on a 2 by 2 matrix M, that will guarantee that the system U' = MU is equivalent to some ODE of the form:
f '' + af '+ bf = 0 (for U = (f, f '))

I have nothing to go on...regardless of what example matrix i take i get some ODE, for example \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} gives me f '' - f ' + 0 * f = 0
Thank you!

Comment: The standard trick is to let $u_1 = f$ and $u_2 = f'$.  Then $u_1'=u_2$ and $u_2' = $ ...?

Comment: Yeah that's if i want to convert high order ODE to first order system, what does that have to do with the condition?

Comment: To clarify the question: Are $a$ and $b$ fixed constants, or does the question say “...equivalent to an ODE of the form $f'' + af' + bf''=0$ for some $a$ and $b$”?

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly, i copied the question as is, but based on previous exercises im fairly certain that "for some a and b" is implied.